# Could not deploy package. Inner Exception: Unable to connect to target server

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

**What minimum user permission required on window computer to install DACPAC through DACFX API (C#)**. The issue i am facing is during impersonation. I am not sure what minimum window permissions required for a domain user being used to impersonate. If i am adding that user(Impersonation user) in admin group on that machine then DACPAC execute successfully, but client don't want to add that user as admin on that window machine. I am clear about SQL server permissions for DAPAC, that user is member of DB_OWNER so SQL server is not the issue but window security.